# I have a dataset with one target column and two text columns.It is an nlp problem which i am trying to solve through deep learning

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, tokenize

I am dealing with a dataset where I have 3 fields. One field is my target field and the other two field are text fields. It is basically an NLP based problem statement. I am trying to approach a deep learning mechanism but while taking into account the two text fields I am getting an error at tokenizing the X_train data post train test split.
I have already read the dataset and label encoded the target column. I have cleaned up the text columns and used stemmer to further lemmatize them. I have stored the two text columns in X and the target column in y. Then, I have performed a train test split.After that I am trying to tokenize X_train which is giving me an error. Review Text and Review Title are text columns.

```
df=pd.read_csv('train_amazon.csv')
df.head(10)

df['topic'].nunique()

df['topic'].value_counts()

df['Review Text'].isnull().any()

df['Review Title'].isnull().any()

df['topic'].isnull().any()

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
df['topic'] = le.fit_transform(df['topic'])

df.head()

le.classes_

dummy_y = pd.get_dummies(df['topic']).values

X =df.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dummy_y

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 101)

tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train)
vocabulary_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
vocabulary_size
```

I am getting the error as follows:-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-7ab7cb886988> in <module>
      1 tokenizer = Tokenizer()
----> 2 tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train)
      3 vocabulary_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
      4 vocabulary_size

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\text.py in fit_on_texts(self, texts)
    221                                             self.filters,
    222                                             self.lower,
--> 223                                             self.split)
    224             for w in seq:
    225                 if w in self.word_counts:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\text.py in text_to_word_sequence(text, filters, lower, split)
     41     """
     42     if lower:
---> 43         text = text.lower()
     44 
     45     if sys.version_info < (3,):

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

My X_train has a shape (4469,2)

and my X_train looks like :-

```
array([['use sinc seal miss', 'broken seal'],
       ['took week immedi effect 1 2 hour hour ingest includ tingl extrem slight relax probabl help anxieti much like medic numb make care less what is bother you howev product made difficult focus short term memori sever impact bout week stuff good detail orient job trust take longer sinc long term effect like unknown care take unregul supplements!!!!',
        'careless'],
       ['smell aw mean rancid could make sick sooooo annoy wish could money back',
        'rancid pill'],
       ...,
       ['didn t realiz serv size capsul purchas huge deal fault prefer take pill vitamin idea it s work help',
        'vitamin yeah'],
       ['horribl taste! wast money', 'horribl fake tast'],
       ['nasti stuff work with thick dropper doesn t work well finger bottl leav sticki mess don t lick bitter',
        'nasti']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Please post a sample of your `X_train` (not here, edit & update your post); plus, question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Hey, I have added my X_train